# Unit Of Work / Repository Pattern, Type Not Found In Cache

Tags: c#, wpf, repository, mvvm-light

I am trying to implement a repository pattern for learning purposes in a project. I am using MVVM Light to register interfaces and am trying to inject into a view model.

I have removed all the other repositories for ease of reading and only included the RuleRepository.

**View Model Locator**

The code breaks when trying to register the IUnitOfWork and gives the error - **Type not found in cache: YAI.BomConfigurator.Core.Context.BomConfiguratorContext.**

Note: Not sure if I need to register the IRepository interface here?

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, Design.DesignDataService>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        }
        else
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        }
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<LoginViewModel>();
    }

    public LoginViewModel LoginViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<LoginViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

**LoginViewModel**

Here is where I try and inject an IUnitOfWork into the view model.

```
public class LoginViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _UnitOfWork;
    public LoginViewModel(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
}
```

**IUnitOfWork**

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IRuleRepository Rules { get; }
    int Complete();
}
```

**UnitOfWork**

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly BomConfiguratorContext _context;
    public IRuleRepository Rules { get; private set; }

    public UnitOfWork(BomConfiguratorContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public int Complete()
    {
        return _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**RuleRepository**

```
public class RuleRepository : Repository<Rule>,IRuleRepository
{
    public RuleRepository(BomConfiguratorContext context)
       : base(context)
    {

    }
}
```

I copied a lot of this from Mosh Hamedani [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtXpYpZdOzM) and tried adding in the bit where we inject into the constructor of the view model. I am a newbie at dependency injection and IOC containers so not to sure what exactly I am doing wrong here.

If someone could give me a good explanation as to what I need to change etc. that would be great. I know many people believe the Unit of Work / Repository Pattern is an anti pattern but I am not concerned about that, this is purely for learning purposes.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: The error seems to indicate `BomConfiguratorContext` is not registered with the DI container

Comment: Am I supposed to register it? How would I do so? @CoryNelson

Comment: I'm not familiar with MVVM Light, so couldn't say. Your issue is with your usage of that though, not anything to do with unit of work / repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not only injecting an instance of UnitOfWork into LoginViewModel, you are also injecting an instance of BomConfiguratorContext into UnitOfWork when you instantiate UnitOfWork:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly BomConfiguratorContext _context;
    public IRuleRepository Rules { get; private set; }

    // here you inject a BomConfiguratorContext, but none is registered in the VM Locator
    public UnitOfWork(BomConfiguratorContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    ...
}
```

So you need to change your ViewModelLocator to also register BomConfiguratorContext:

```
static ViewModelLocator()
{
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

    if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
    {
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, Design.DesignDataService>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
    }
    else
    {
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
    }
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<LoginViewModel>();

    // Missing something like this (not sure what interface it implements...)
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IConfiguratorContext, BomConfiguratorContext>();
}
```

Comment: I don't actually have an interface for my context. I registered just the BomConfiguratorContext and made it past the constructor, but then when trying to query the collection it says my _UnitOfWork.Rules is null? Not really sure what is going on.

Comment: That's because you declare it but never instantiate it: `public IRuleRepository Rules { get; private set; }` - you never assign anything to this property, so it remains null.  You need to add `Rules = new RuleRepository()` in your constructor or use dependency injection for this also, like `public UnitOfWork(BomConfiguratorContext context, IRuleRespository rulesRepo)`

Comment: And if you use DI, you need to register this into SimpleIoc also or you will run into the same issue you were talking about initially...

Comment: Okay I see what you mean, now I will probably need to use a factory to instantiate my repos, I currently have like 5 but will probably grow to like 8.  (If I go the DI route for initializing them)

Comment: Either approach should work.  I can't think of anything wrong with registering all 8 with DI if you want to go that route.  Hopefully this helped you get to the root of the problem - if so, an accepted answer would be appreciated!  Good luck.

Comment: I don't believe there will be a problem with registering all 8, just passing all 8 interfaces to the Unit Of Work Constructor. Thank you for the help!.